# How to vertically align an inputAdornment so it remains at the top in a multiline MUI TextField

Tags: reactjs, vertical-alignment, multiline, textinput, adornment

Using react I have a MUI multiline FieldText with a couple of  inputAdornment icons aligned to the right.

As I fill it in, the box changes its height for every new line and the icons are **vertically centered in the middle**.

I am trying to make the icons remain aligned at the top but haven't been able to. Is there a way?

Sorry I cannot provide examples but I am barred from embedding images. Hope my question is clear and thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Make the parent of the adornment relatively positioned and then position the adornment with absolute positioning, then you can put it wherever you'd like!

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this:

```
  <div sx={{position: 'relative'}}>
        <InputAdornment sx={{position: 'absolute', top: 0}}>
    ///icons
        </InputAdornment>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're talking about using the MUI component library so this is how I did it. Using the sx property of TextField, you can style the component with `alignItems:"flex-start"` which will top-justify all elements, including the input adornment:

```
<TextField
    label={"Comment"}
    multiline
    minRows={1}
    maxRows={4}
    fullWidth={true}
    onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
    value={currentComment}
    InputProps={{
        endAdornment: <Button variant="contained" disabled={submitBtnDisabled}
                              onClick={submitNewComment}
                              sx={{
                                  marginLeft:"6px",
        }}
        >Submit</Button>,
        sx: {
            "& .css-3fezr7-MuiInputBase-root-MuiOutlinedInput-root" : {
                padding: "4px 8px 4px 8px"
            },
            fontSize: ".875rem;",
            alignItems:"flex-start"
        }
    }}/>
```

Here's how it looks for me:
[image: flex-start example]

Using this same method, you could also align it to the bottom using `alignItems:"flex-end"`